# Проблема с хранимой процедурой в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

У меня есть две модели:

```
public class User
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public Role Role { get; set; }
public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Обращаю внимание, что в классе User объявляется:

```
public Role Role { get; set; }
```

Если я извлекаю данные из базы следующим образом:

```
User user = db.Users.Include(u => u.Role).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == model.UserId);
```

То все отлично, я получаю экземпляр класса User, со всеми заполненными членами, в том числе User содержит Role, из которого я могу взять Name.

Посмотрев SQL запрос, который EF отправляет в базу, увидел следующее:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_GetUserWithRole] 
@UserID int
AS
SELECT 
[Limit1].[Id] AS [Id],  
[Limit1].[Email] AS [Email],
[Limit1].[Password] AS [Password],
[Limit1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
[Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Limit1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Roles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RoleId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserID] = @UserID
)  AS [Limit1]
END
```

Скопировал код этого запроса и создал из него хранимую процедуру

Извлекаю данные из базы с помощью этой хранимой процедуры:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserId);
var U = Database.SqlQuery<User>("User_GetUserWithRole @UserID", param);
```

Когда тестирую эту хранимую процедуру в MsSQL Managment Studio, она возвращает все данные, в том числе и поле Name из таблицы Role. Но когда просматриваю переменную U,то Name в ней отсутствует и Role = null. Получается хранимая процедура не может корректно сформировать объект User в результате выполнения запроса, но почему так?

Comment: UserId установлен и такой же как model.UserId, да?

Comment: @A K да одинаковые

Answer (score 1):

Либо вы неправильно скопировали, либо неправильно что-то заменили руками, обратите внимание на этот участок кода

```
WHERE [Extent1].[UserID] = @UserID
```

Где у вас есть такое поле UserID?

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто не вставил сюда этот параметр. Да он присутствует в хранимой процедуре и она отлично работает, но вот в коде проблема, которую я описал.